# Sets equinumerisity.

Tags: set-theory

Prove that for infinite set $A \setminus B$ and countable set $B$ it is true that $A \setminus B$ and A equinumerous.

Have tried to apply fact that every infinite set contains countable one, however don't understand what to do with elements enumeration needed for bijection..
P.S Problem topic has changed

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, yeah, thanks.

Comment: False.  
N - { k in N : k >= n } has finite cardinality n.  
Obviously it is not equinumerous to N.  
For the proposition to be true, infinite must mean uncountable.  
Another possibility would to make countable mean finite.  
Yes, every infinite set contains a countable set,  
but that is useless to prove that false statement.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, but what about the answer to mentioned question? There is said, that it is true..

Comment: Three cases:   A infinite, B finite;   A and B denumberable;   A uncountable, B countable.  The reference answer is for yet a different problem.

Comment: Yes, the referenced solution is for a different pronlem.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, may you please provide your full solution, if it is possible, as I don't understand the problem yet, I've posted question again: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558624/set-problem-again

Comment: Let $X = (A\setminus B)$ and let $Y = B$.  The linked question shows how for infinite $X$ and countable $Y$ that $|X\cup Y| = |X|$... which rewritten with our $A$'s and $B$'s shows how for infinite $A\setminus B$ that $|(A\setminus B)\cup B| = |(A\setminus B)|$ or simplified how $|A|=|A\setminus B|$, exactly as you request.  The linked problem *is* relevant and *is* a duplicate of this one, just worded slightly differently.