# Prove that for infinite set $A\setminus B$ and countable set $B$, $ |A\setminus B|= |A|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that for infinite set $A\setminus B$ and countable set $B$ it is true that 
$A\setminus B$ and $A$ are equinumerous.

Have tried to apply fact that every infinite set contains countable one, however don't understand what to do with elements enumeration needed for bijection..
P.S First came up with this problem here: [Sets equinumerisity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558147/sets-equinumerisity), however referenced solution seems to be for different task..

Comment: Rechecked, everything seems to be right...

Comment: Let $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $|\emptyset|\neq |\mathbb{Z}|$

Comment: Ah, *infinite set (A\B)*, as in (A\B) is infinite.  I retract my earlier comment then.  That said, recognize that $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B$ and so $|A| = |(A\setminus B)\cup B| = |A\setminus B|+|B|$.  At this point, the linked duplicate that your earlier question was closed as a duplicate of *is* in fact relevant.